# Should I use an Enum or String in a JComboBox

Tags: java, swing

Just came across a slight issue I'm confused by if someone wouldn't mind having a quick look please.

My ComboBoxes are constructed and initialised as shown below, with me thinking it would be a good idea to keep the data as enums, as the options are all fixed:

`private JComboBox<JobTitle> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();`

but when adding elements to the DefaultComboBoxModel I've realised that I don't want to display the options as a constant (ie I don't want the options to be displayed in capitals).

So I created my enum like this (see below) in order to call `jobTitleModel.addElement(JobTitle.Architect.getName())`
But obviously that isn't going to work as the ComboBox is of type enum, not string.

```
public enum JobTitle {
    ARCHITECT("Architect"), TOWN_PLANNER("Town Planner"), URBAN_DESIGNER("Urban Designer"), LANDSCAPE_GARDENER("Landscape Gardener");

    private final String name;

    private JobTitle(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
         return this.name;
    }
}
```

So I'm not really sure how to approach this? I could change the ComboBox and model to String, but I think I must be missing something obvious here. Thanks

Comment: Use enums but give the combo box a custom renderer that displays the enum text appropriately.

Comment: Here is an example of [how to fill a `JComboBox` with enum variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42603111/2180785)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the name `getName()`. It's liable to be confused with the `name()` method.

Comment: good point. i didn't particularly want to name the variable 'name' either - i was just trying things out. will make sure i change both, thanks

Comment: I usually use text and `getText()` for these guys

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What about good old `toString()`? According to [Enum#name()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name--): "_... **Most programmers should use the `toString()` method in preference to this one, as the toString method may return a more user-friendly name.** ..._".

Comment: @GeroldBroser: which should always be used for debugging purposes and *never* for end-user interface

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Why would you say that? There are classes that use it to support core functionality, like `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom renderer for your JComboBox. For example the code below uses a renderer that extends from the default list cell renderer. All it does is to get the value held in each cell of the JComboBox, a JobTitle object, extracts the name from this object, and displays the name:

```
JComboBox<JobTitle> jobCombo = new JComboBox<>(JobTitle.values());
jobCombo.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list,
            Object value,
            int index,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {
        value = ((JobTitle) value).getName();
        return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    }

});
```

Why do this? Now if the user selects an item from the combo box, it is a full-fledged JobTitle enum object and not a String.

---

Regarding your comment:

> If I wanted to make a method that does the above for a variety of comboBoxes and enums, is a switch the most elegant way to deal with that cast on line 9?

That's a whole new question and probably should be posted separately, but one possible solution is to give all the enums the same interface, something like:

```
public enum JobTitle implements Textable {
    ARCHITECT("Architect"), TOWN_PLANNER("Town Planner"), URBAN_DESIGNER(
            "Urban Designer"), LANDSCAPE_GARDENER("Landscape Gardener");

    private final String text;

    private JobTitle(String name) {
        this.text = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

```
public interface Textable {
    String getText();
}
```

And then creating my own renderer class:

```
public class TextableRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        value = ((Textable) value).getText();

        return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    }
}
```

This will work with any enum (or class) that implements the Textable interface.

And then used:

```
final JComboBox<JobTitle> jobCombo = new JComboBox<>(JobTitle.values());
jobCombo.setRenderer(new TextableRenderer());
```

Comment: Nice. Haven't seen an answer from you long time.

Comment: @GhostCat: yeah, too busy closing questions!

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect - and helps me start to look into renderers a bit more. I've been avoiding them :)

Comment: If I wanted to make a method that does the above for a variety of comboBoxes and enums, is a switch the most elegant way to deal with that cast on line 9? I'm trying it now....

Comment: Nice! I really like that. When I saw all the code my first thought was 'that's a lot of code for what I want to do', but I'm going to do that. Thanks again, I really appreciate it